# jQuery div overlay on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

[Here is a simplified example of what it is](http://jsfiddle.net/bGa34/).
All I want is to make one gray div on its hover. However, everything becomes in gray. And I don't understand why.

The code is below:

```
<style>
#myclient > li{
    display: inline-block;
    width:140px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#myclient > li a{
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    height: 222px;
    position: relative;
}
#myclient > li img{
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.myhover{
    background-color: rgba(50,50,50,1);
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
</style>
<ul id="myclient">
    <li><a href="#">1</a>
        <div class="myhover" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a>
        <div class="myhover" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a>
        <div class="myhover" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a>
        <div class="myhover" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a>
        <div class="myhover" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myclient").on("mouseenter", "li", function(){                       
        $(this).find('.myhover').fadeIn(400);
    }).on("mouseleave", "li", function(){   
        $(this).find('.myhover').stop().fadeOut(100);
    })  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your overlay is absolute against the whole body. Make it relative to the parent `<li>`:

```css
#myclient > li {
    position: relative;

    /* ... */
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bGa34/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#myclient > li{
    display: inline-block;
    width:140px;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bGa34/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/5tQUs/)

```
#myclient > li{
    display: inline-block;
    width:140px;
    margin-right:10px;
    position: relative;
}
```